# element complexType name attribute

Tags: c#, wsdl, asmx

How can I specify "name" attribute for "complexType" tag inside "element" tag? For exampl smth. like this:

```
<s:element name="recvMail">
    <s:complexType name="recvMail">
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element name="bMail"  type="tns:bMail"  minOccurs="0"/>
        <s:element name="bTrace" type="tns:bTrace" minOccurs="0"/>
        <s:element name="bBody"  type="tns:bBody"  minOccurs="0"/>
        <s:element name="bSign" type="s:string"   minOccurs="0"/>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
```

I'm using ASP.NET .ASMX web service, tried many attributes. I've been surfing over google for 2 days, but nothing found. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

```
 [WebMethod(BufferResponse = false, CacheDuration = 60, EnableSession = false)]
 [SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace = "http://temp.ws.uri/", ResponseNamespace = "http://temp.ws.uri/", Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal,
   ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
 [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("bAnswer")]
 public bAnswer recvMail(bMail bMail, bTrace bTrace, bBody bBody, string bSign) { ... }
```